# ELK - Elastic / Logstash / Kibana - Configuration for AKAMAI Logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Can anyone help in setting up **Akamai** Logs in **Logstash** **Kibana**?

> 2016-10-19    23:57:32  192.168.0.1 GET /origin-www.example.com/url   200
>   1144    0   "-"   "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-" "-"

That's one line entry. Need help understanding the pattern or if anyone can provide me any direction at all, this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an apache log.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have created the index in kibana / elastic already. However, I need to map the data through patterns. The sample entry is in the description above. Any idea how I can load my log file in the elastic index? Any help would be appreciated @alain

Comment: If you have the data in elasticsearch already, then it's "loaded".  Perhaps you're trying to parse the data into fields?  If so, check out logstash's grok{} filter, which can apply a regular expression to your input message and create fields.  There are some good tutorials around the internet.

Comment: to help you for the grok filter: [grok filter tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [base grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).